# Test a value of multiple columns, Access SQL from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I want to import a table from Access DB, in this table there is a column that is valued and not, when not I want to fill this column on the result table with a default value or let it empty.

```
I tried  IsNull(col2 ,'')
```

Thanks in advance

```
MyQuery = "SELECT col1 AS col1, col2 AS myDevice";
MyQuery += " FROM table 1";
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(MyQuery, conn);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
adapter1.Fill(table);
DB.Tables.Add(table);
```

Comment: with Nz function I got this : Undefined function 'Nz' in expression.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, you want [the `Nz()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

```
Nz(col2 ,'default')
```

[`IsNull()` exists in Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/isnull-function-f963233b-1c1e-4b0c-8bc3-3e8c0ea67c61?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) but it is meant to check if a value is `null` (and it returns a boolean value).

Comment: SQL equivalant of Nz is `CAOLESCE` (and for IsNull it is `IS NULL`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this:

```
MyQuery = "SELECT col1 AS col1, IIF(ISNULL(col2), 0, col2) AS myDevice";
```

Thanks